# How to turn off auto indenting while editing a LaTeX file?

Tags: indentation, filetype-tex

I edit a LaTeX file, and for some commands Vim does auto indenting.

I would like to switch it off.

Consulting:

https://www.serverwatch.com/guides/automatic-indenting-vim/

I tried:

```
:filetype indent off
```

and:

```
:set paste
```

but they did not work, Vim sometimes puts a leading tab before my commands.

How can I switch off auto indenting for my LaTeX files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable auto indentation you can do:

```
:set noautoindent
:set indentexpr=
```

If you want to make automatic for all LaTeX files you could add a `tex.vim` file within `~/.vim/after/indent/` folder with the following content:

```
setlocal noautoindent
setlocal indentexpr=
```

Comment: It did not work. I don't know which part of vim does this, but when I write a command starting with backslash, write the command name and enter an opening curly brace, vim adds a leading tab to the line.

Comment: I have reproduced your problem and adapted the solution accordingly :-)

Comment: I have created the tex.vim file in the mentioned directory and now indentation is reliably turned off

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Comment: Is there a particular reason to put this below the `after` folder?  I don't seem to need that ... ?  (I.e., the `indent` folder on level higher seems to work.)

Comment: @Alan: The `~/.vim/indent/tex.vim` is executed before `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/tex.vim` that is executed `~/.vim/after/indent/tex.vim`. If you want to be sure to override what is done `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/tex.vim` a solution is to make it in `~/.vim/after/indent/tex.vim`. Of course if nothing is done in `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/tex.vim` it is ok to do the change in `~/.vim/indent/tex.vim` :-)