# How can I ignore default filetype indenting?

Tags: neovim, filetype-tex

Can I tell Neovim not to load a bundled indentation file?  For example, when I edit a .tex file, "share/nvim/runtime/indent/tex.vim" loads automatically.  I don't want those settings.  Do I have to override them, or can I just put something in my local "indent/tex.lua" to stop the defaults from loading? (If so, what?)

**Edit:** If I replace my local `indent/tex.lua` with `indent/tex.vim` and say `let b:did_indent = 1` that works fine. But I want to know how to do this using Lua. A pointer to documentation of how to access the appropriate namespace is all I really need.

**Edit 2:** Commenters say that having `vim.b.did_indent = 1` in my local `indent/tex.lua` (*not* under `after`) should have the same effect as putting `let b:did_indent = 1` in `indent/tex.vim`. I have tried these two approaches (one at a time), and they do not have the same effect. (The files contain only one line, as just stated.) In particular, when I use the `tex.vim` file, the value of `indentexpr` is the empty string (as I wish and expect). But when I use the `tex.lua` file, the value of `indentexpr` is `GetTeXIndent()`, which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Is the following [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/41855/23502) of any help?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I have Neovim 0.9.1.  If I put `vim.b.did_indent = 1` in my local `indent/tex.lua` (not `after`) it *does not* turn off the default indenting.  If I instead create `indent/tex.vim` with the content `let b:did_indent = 1`, it *does* turn off the default indenting. I think (?) the two shd have the same effect. Thanks!

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allows the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:
`~/.config/nvim/indent/tex.lua` as:

```lua
vim.o.indentexpr=""
```

Remark on version prior to 9.3:

- `~/.config/indent/tex.lua` is executed after `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/tex.vim`
- Where `~/.config/indent/tex.lua` is executed before `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/tex.vim`

This is the reason the following translation of the `tex.vim` trick is not working:

`~/.config/nvim/indent/tex.lua`

```lua
vim.b.did_indent = 1
```

Remark: It seems that from version 9.3 the trick should work

Comment: Have you actually tried this? I have Neovim 0.9.1.  If I put `vim.b.did_indent = 1` in my local `indent/tex.lua` it *does not* turn off the default indenting.  If I instead create `indent/tex.vim` with the content `let b:did_indent = 1`, it *does* turn off the default indenting.

Comment: I'm using Neovim 0.9.1 and `b:did_indent` is 1 for `tex` files. I don't know enough about the autoindenting you try to avoid (an example would be nice) so I couldn't test that. But the variable is correctly set for `tex` buffers.

Comment: With the configuration you describe above (a `tex.lua` but not a `tex.vim` in your indent folder), go to a .tex document. Create an empty equation environment on two lines, unindented. Put your cursor in indent mode at the end of the first of these two lines (which should be right after a closing brace) and press Enter. Do you see any indentation? Also, what is the value of `indentexpr`? Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide me the text (I don't recall our to do an empty equation :-|)? Maybe you could add the example to the question.

Comment: OK, skip that for now and see Edit 2 (just added). So with *only* the `tex.lua` file (and *no* `tex.vim` file) in the `indent` folder, please open a `.tex` file and in normal mode press `:set indentexpr?`. What do you see?  Thanks!

Comment: `indentexpr=` is blank. With my bar configuration of Neovim `.tex` file are or `plaintex` filetype. It has no indentation by default. I wonder if you have a installed a plugin (e.g. [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex)) support TeX and LaTeX.

Comment: So if you remove `tex.lua` from the `indent` folder and do the same experiment, is `indentexpr` still the empty string?  (Does "bare configuration" mean that you do not even have the standard `runtime/indent/tex.vim` file, which sets `indentexpr`?)

Comment: I have installed [vimtex]() to reproduce your problem and I notice that `~/.config/indent/tex.lua` is executed after `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/tex.vim` which makes that the trick isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

1. Type `:help user-manual`
2. Type `/indenting`
3. See section 30.3 Automatic indenting
4. Press `K` to follow the link
5. Read the text
6. Find the commands `filetype indent off`, `let b:did_indent=1` etc.etc.

Upd. As for `vim.b.did_indent=1` not working (executing only after standard `tex.vim`) that turns out to be a bug in older nvim runtime (`indent.vim`). This was already fixed in the current (v10) branch. This is why one must update the installation to the latest build before trying to reproduce any supposed bugs.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148686/discussion-on-answer-by-matt-how-can-i-ignore-default-filetype-indenting); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.